# How can I compile and install the latest FFmpeg on Linux?

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg

I want to install the latest version of ffmpeg on Linux (Ubuntu/Debian). It should meet requirements to stream via rtmp, convert streams with x264, create segment files to stream to IOS devices. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The FFmpeg wiki has a [compilation guide for Ubuntu](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide). There's also one [for CentOS](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide). Since the guides are constantly updated for future releases, there is no point in copying all the information here.

When following the Ubuntu guide, you will install the following additional encoders from source:

- x264: you need this for streaming
- fdk-aac: this provides way better quality AAC than the FFmpeg-native AAC encoder
- vpx: for WebM streaming you should install this as well
- opus: purely optional, not needed

With the CentOS guide, the following are manual installs in addition to the ones mentioned above:

- LAME: this is the MP3 encoder you should use
- libogg and libvorbis: for Theora video and Vorbis audio

---

Instead of manually compiling FFmpeg, you can also [download a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from the homepage. These are Git snapshots, so they're always fresh. The static builds don't include `ffserver` by the way.

<sub>**Note:** For licensing reasons they can't bundle FAAC or FDK-AAC. They *do* include libvo-aacenc, but it also doesn't give you any better quality than the native AAC encoder in FFmpeg.</sub>